# Convert strings to floats or double from a list c#

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert all the number from a list of strings to float. I'm not sure why all the items from the list are char, and it converts every single digit to char instead of converting the number until space. Below is the code. If the first input is 2, it will create 2 lists, let's say `12 23 33` and `22 33 44`.

From list 1, I need `mm` to be `12/23/33` instead of `1/2/2/3/3/3`

```
int nrMagazine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

List<String> mag = new List<String>();

string prop = "";
for(int i = 0; i < nrMagazine;i++)
{
    string profitTrimestre = Console.ReadLine();
    profitTrimestre.Split();
    mag.Add(profitTrimestre);

    //cel mai profitabil trimestru,trimestru 1 = m[0],1=m[1]
    //cel mai profitabil magazin,mag 1,2,3,4,n
}
foreach(string m in mag)
{
    foreach(string mm in m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mm);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need 1 `foreach`, which will interact with the list itens. `m` is already a string, so the second `foreach` is iterating over the chars of that string. Also `profitTrimestre.Split();` returns an array that you're discarting, `profitTrimestre` is what the user has inputed.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` - That's just an exception waiting to happen. **Never trust user input!**. Use `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: the thing is the user will input 4 floats separated by 1 space,the input doesn`t have to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to split your line on spaces instead and actually assign the split value to mag?

```
string[] mag = profitTrimestre.Split(' ');
```

Then you should be able to loop over each string in that list with just one foreach:

```
foreach(string m in mag)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

If you want to convert the individual string parts to Doubles, you can do that like this:

```
double d = double.Parse(m);
```

You can also do it like this, if you want to avoid exceptions if the strings aren't valid double representations:

```
double.TryParse(m, out double d);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your current code.

> I m not sure why all the items from the list are char

Because you have another loop for string which implicitly using enumerator iterates the string by character. You should be able to convert to float by using `Convert` class :

```
foreach(string m in mag)
{
    var number = Convert.ToDouble(m);
}
```

Secondly if numbers are space delimited then use `Split` overload that takes character to use for splitting :

```
var splitted = profitTrimestre.Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and then loop :

```
foreach(var item in splitted)
  mag.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = Console.ReadLine();
        var strings = text.Split(' '); // This splits the 11 22 33 to three string values.
        var numbers = strings.Select(a =>
        {
            if (float.TryParse(a, out float number))
                return number;
            return 0;
        }).ToList(); // This converts 3 strings to 3 float
    }
```

Or you can try the shortest version (thanks to Prasad Telkikar)

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), x => float.TryParse(x, out float number) ? number : 0);
    }
```

Comment: What about one liner `Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(' '), x => float.TryParse(x, out float number) ? number : 0).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

`profitTrimestre.Split();` will return an array, which currently you're doing nothing with it.  Try change to this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert the number of lists: ");
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out int nrMagazine)) //Never trust user's inputs
{
    List<string> mag = new List<string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nrMagazine;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Insert List {i+1}: ");
        mag.Add(Console.ReadLine());    
    }
    foreach(string m in mag) //iterates over each input string
    {
        foreach(string mm in m.Split(' ')) //splits each entry and iterates over the itens
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mm);
            if(double.TryParse(mm, out double myDouble)) //You can also pass a Culture
            {
                //Do something with your double
            }
            else
            {
                //Input not a double in the current culture
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The input was not an integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you need.

```
        Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<float>> nrMagazine = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<float>>(); //creates dictionary

        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int x); //input number for iterations here

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            nrMagazine.Add(i, Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => { float.TryParse(s, out float y); return y; })); //builds floats list and adds it to dictionary x times
        }

        nrMagazine.Keys.ToList().ForEach((i) => Console.WriteLine("Magazine: " + i + ", Profits:  " + String.Join(", ", nrMagazine[i]))); //prints items from dictionary
```